# C# to PHP script UploadData

Tags: c#, php, webclient

I have C#  function that send byte[] to PHP script using this method

`webclient.uploadData(string,string,byte[])`

anyone tell me how I can get that byte[] array in PHP script??

I tried $_POST,$_REQUEST,$_FILE but I didn't got the same bytes which I send from c# function!!

C# function :

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(FileLocation); 
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
var text = client.UploadData(URL + "?" + postData), "POST", data);    
MessageBox.Show(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(text));
```

PHP

`print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Can you show some example? What you send and what you received?

Comment: $_POST should work, provided you are using `uploadData` correctly - see this example - http://www.daveamenta.com/2008-05/c-webclient-usage/

Comment: You need to read file content in string, and use it like this wc.UploadData(url, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data=" +<FILECONTENT>) ); I am not sure what is `postData` in your case, in 4th line.

Comment: PostData are just some values like www.google.com?value=1&abc=123 etc
"value=1&abc=123" this is postdata

Comment: So my next question, what you are interested in getting in PHP side, is it post data or `value=1`, `abc=123`?

Comment: @ArindamNayak not working!

Comment: Could you please post the output of `echo file_get_contents("php://input");`? That would be helpful to understand in which format the data is transmitted.

Comment: @ArindamNayak it post data but these are attached with url!

Comment: @Niko it just print MZ?

Comment: @AdeelSatti , i didn't get you, can you explain more?

Comment: @ArindamNayak I want to know how I can get byte array which I send through c# UploadData, how to get that array in php just tell me php function that give me byte[] array!!!

Comment: Adeel, please provide a sample text file that you are using(like `sample.txt` contains one string: `"Test"`), then provide more code of what each parameter/variable is, what your `PHP` script looks like, more information is what everyone is asking. It's very hard to help you with such little data you provided...